# How to display information from database onchange

Tags: php, html, mysql

I made a dropdownlist with values from my database. Now I'd like to show information from that same database when I choose another value in the dropdownlist. For example, I choose the team Angels in my dropdownlist and then I would like to show information, that's in the database, about the team Angels. I would really like to know how to do that.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id1419279_root";
$password = "******";
$dbname = "id1419279_mlb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM teams";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$dropdownlist = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$teamnaam = $row['teamnaam'];

$dropdownlist .="<option value='" . $teamnaam . "'>" . $teamnaam . "
</option>";

}

if(isset($dropdownlist)){

echo "<select name='naamteam' onchange='submit()'>";

echo $dropdownlist;

echo "</select>";
}

?>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['naamteam'])) {

$naamteam = $_POST['teamnaam'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM spelers WHERE naamteam = '$teamnaam'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "{$row['teamnaam']} <br>";
echo "{$row['coach']} <br>";
echo "{$row['info']} <br>";
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better will be to use Onchange jquery event and send that data with AJAX to another file which will get your ajax request and there you can set your queries to get data based on your onchange value and then append the result wherever you need to show.

Comment: Well I don't really have any experience with AJAX so that probably won't go so well and I have a deadline tomorrow hahaha